# Why is the beginning of a line not recognized by a regex?

Tags: java, regex

given the following expression:

```
Pattern.compile("^Test.*\n").matcher("Test 123\nNothing\nTest 2\n").replaceAll("foo\n")
```

This yields:

```
"foo\nNothing\nTest 2\n"
```

for me. I expected that the last line is also replaced to `foo\n` since there is a linebreak immediately before `Test 2` in the input string.

Why is doesn't the regex match there?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the multiline flag to the pattern: `Pattern.MULTILINE`.

```
Pattern.compile("^Test.*\n", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher("Test 123\nNothing\nTest 2\n").replaceAll("foo\n")
```

By Default the match is only single line. For more Informations see [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your regex you have a `^` sign which normally anchors the regex to the beginning of a tested string. You need to specify multiline regex option ([Oracle Documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE)) to make it apply to start of each line instead.

Try this (I have split the lines for legibility, feel free to oneline it back):

```
Pattern.compile("^Test.*\n", Pattern.MULTILINE)
       .matcher("Test 123\nNothing\nTest 2\n")
       .replaceAll("foo\n")
```

Unfortunately I do not have Java environment set up at the moment, so I'm unable to check this by myself.